# pass $scope value of a constructor function to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

> Here i want to pass *$scope.myData* of **app.js** to the directive *mcsaForm* and use the object attributes in **myTemplate.html**. My code is working properly except the approach which i mentioned above.
>
> app.js

```
myApp.controller("myCont", function($scope){
   .
    some code
   .
   .
   $scope.getTypeOfEvent = function(typeOfEvent, idOfEvent)
   {
       if(typeOfEvent == "MCQ")
       {
       
         if(idOfEvent)
         {
            var indexOfEvent =$scope.namesTwo.Events.indexOf("idOfEvent")+1;
            var valueAtIndex = $scope.namesTwo.Events[indexOfEvent].id;
            $scope.myData = $scope.namesTwo[valueAtIndex];
            console.log($scope.myData); // output: Object {eventId: "001", TimeOfEvent: "2", EventType: "MCQ"}
         }
         //fetchJsonDir.gettingContData;
         $scope.mCSSQ(typeOfEvent,idOfEvent);
       }
   }
});
```

> myDirective.js

```
videoCourseApp.directive("mcsaForm",['fetchJsonDir', function(fetchJsonDir){
return{
    restrict: "C",
    templateUrl: "assets/template_blocks/Preview_forms/myTemplate.html",
    scope: {
        myData: "="
    },
    compile: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {   
        $("#mcss_option_list").append("Hello");
    },
    controller: function($scope){     
        $scope.onSubmitHidePanel = function()
        {
            $(".mcsa_form").fadeOut("slow", function(){ 
                    $(this).remove();
            });-
        }
    }
}
}]);
```

> myTemplate.html

```
<div id=mcss_option_list>
    
</div>
<div>
     001, 2, MCQ//print myData.eventId, myData.TimeOfEvent or whatever..
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your directive like

```
<div class="mcsa-form" my-data="myData"></div>
```

You will get the value in your directive's `myTemplate.html`

```
<div id=mcss_option_list>
   {{myData.TimeOfEvent}}
</div>
```